# __metadata type to upload image into SharePoint through API

Tags: json, image, sharepoint, hyperlink, metadata

Does anyone know the json syntax to push an image to SharePoint?
For example, this is the syntax to send a hyperlink. I'm trying to find a similar syntax for an image
[JSON syntax for pushing hyperlink to SharePoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEnPz.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, the value of image type column returns as string in sharepoint.

[image]

The value would be like this:

```
"image": "{\"fileName\":\"test.png\",\"serverRelativeUrl\":\"/sites/test/SiteAssets/Lists/09c0d356-d858-475f-84c8-92956e39bebc/test.png\",\"id\":\"d5e322a2-acae-449e-8a7c-a44ba8140b40\",\"serverUrl\":\"https://tenant.sharepoint.com\",\"thumbnailRenderer\":{\"spItemUrl\":\"https://tenant.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.1/drives/b!WDKPPfuaoUW1TbE8sgKE8ue4WXMiqthMpU8kax5oRQYsmOWYL1uFRopqDvUl61Wb/items/014HB4BA5CELR5LLVMTZCIU7FEJOUBIC2A\",\"fileVersion\":1,\"sponsorToken\":\"L3NpdGVzL3Rlc3QvTGlzdHMvdGVzdDJ8aW1hZ2V8Mzg\"}}"
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the response. The above given solution is working when the image is in the form of URL. But my image is encoded in base64 format. Please suggest me how to achieve this.  Note: I'm able to send the base64 encoded image to SharePoint and the thumbnail is also displayed in SharePoint. But when we click on thumbnail, a blank screen opens instead of the image.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not supported to add base64 format image in Sharepoint columns